# Java's Heap Structure Implementation

Tags: java, heap-memory

I understand that Java allocates objects in the Heap and why. I understand that primitive data types and references variables are allocated on the Stack structure.

What I don't understand is it's efficiency. It seems to work pretty fast, in comparison to others'.

My questions are related to each other: What makes Java's Heap structure efficient? How is it implemented?

Comment: _"faster than other Heaps' implementation, such that of C."_ Gonna need some benchmarks. Also, the heap implementation depends on the particular JVM you are using, and for any of the popular ones, an in-depth analysis would be too long for an SO answer.

Comment: I learned years ago in a Programming Language's Concepts class that it simulates a stack structure for the objects, using garbage collector for reallocation (although I don't understand how it works). I wonder if this is default in JVMs. If not, I suppose asking how it works is useless... thanks anyway, @Colonel Thirty Two. I'll wait for more feedback and possible answers. I'll also see if I can again write a small algorithm in both Java and C that requires a lot of memory allocation in their Heap structure to have something to compare.

Comment: The ability to move objects around freely is _extremely_ valuable in making memory allocation easy.  Most of the time a heap allocation just allocates the next chunk of memory and increments a pointer somewhere, and then the GC moves all retained objects out of the way so you continue to have just a giant chunk of free memory.

Comment: I ran some small and simple experiments of memory allocation in loops, and got too the conclusion that not necessarily Java's Heap is faster than C's, in therms of allocation. I'm editing the question.

Thanks for the feedback, @Louis Wasserman.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The HotSpot JVM uses a collection of different garbage collectors in tandem with one another to increase efficiency. Since most objects have extremely short lifetimes, it uses a stop-and-copy garbage collector with a small size for most allocations. Since stop-and-copy allows for almost instantaneous allocations (usually one or two assembly instructions), this makes most allocations fast. The cost of doing a "copy" step is low because most objects are reclaimed and the small size reserved for the copy collector gives a good upper-bound on the maximum time spent copying.

For objects that survive a long time in the first layer of the stop-and-copy collector, the HotSpot has a second level of stop-and-copied memory where it relocates those objects. This frees up more space in the top-level copy collector. Objects that survive long enough there are then moved to an area that uses mark-and-sweep collection. The idea is that anything that ends up there is likely to be around a long time because it's survived so long.

This hybrid approach - plus a bunch of other optimizations - explains why allocations and deallocations are so fast. Notice that the key tricks used here - namely, relocating objects - are hard to implement in low-level languages because of exposed pointers.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time explaining all this, @templatetypedef!